# Xamarin Forms Bitmap Coordinates on SkiaSharp Canvas

Tags: ios, xamarin, canvas, bitmap, skiasharp

I have a simple Xamarin Forms page that contains a SkiaSharp Canvas. I am allowing the user to load a floor plan bitmap to use as the background for the Canvas, and they can add smaller bitmaps to be dragged around the canvas where they need.

I am following this guidance on the Microsoft page for touch manipulation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/touch

Everything works perfectly if I use it on a single device size. When I launch it on a different device size, the resolution and Canvas size are different, and it is causing the smaller bitmaps to be placed inconsistently.

Here is the result I am seeing. The left is an iPhone 13 Pro Max, and the right is a iPhone 13 Pro. As you can see, the result is off when I view it on different size devices.

[image: Screenshot of iPhone 13 Pro Max and Pro]

Here is the Grid that contains the SKCanvas:

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="1">
  <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView" PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />
    <Grid.Effects>
      <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True" TouchAction="OnTouchEffectAction" />
    </Grid.Effects>
</Grid>
```

Here is the PaintSurface handler:

```
void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
{
  SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
  SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
  SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

  canvas.Clear();

  //set background
  SKRect dest = new SKRect(0, 0, info.Width, info.Height);
  canvas.DrawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, dest, BitmapStretch.Uniform,
                    BitmapAlignment.Start, BitmapAlignment.Start);

  //Set the coordinates for the pin bitmap
  var transX = 1005;
  var transY = 1189;
  bitmap.Matrix = SKMatrix.CreateTranslation(transX, transY);

  // Display the bitmap
  bitmap.Paint(canvas);

  // Display the matrix in the lower-right corner
  SKSize matrixSize = matrixDisplay.Measure(bitmap.Matrix);

  matrixDisplay.Paint(canvas, bitmap.Matrix,
                      new SKPoint(info.Width - matrixSize.Width,
                            info.Height - matrixSize.Height));
}
```

I've been through several posts on StackOverflow as well as in MS forums. I can't figure out a way to make this show consistently on different size devices.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can keep this smaller bitmap in the same location on the background/SKCanvas regardless of device size?

I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinate of the bitmap is not supposed to be hard-coded , you need to adjust the value (x/y) according to the background canvas's size.

##### Something like this

```
 var transX = info.Width - 20;
 var transY = info.Height - 20;
```

Comment: Hi ColeX, thanks for the reply. I hardcoded the coordinate for demonstration purposes. The real value will be dynamic based on user action. In your example, what does the constant value of "20" represent?

Comment: It means nothing , just give some margin on the bitmap and let it locates at the bottom right corner.

Comment: I think the issue I am running into is that I am basing location on the TouchManipulationInfo class represented in the MSFT examples. They use SKPoint for the location, which is different than the Xamarin Forms location. I've tried converting back and forth between the two using the Extension Methods they've provided, but it just is not working as I'd expect. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Could you show the code what you've tried ?